# Add filter for user email on Zimbra server

Tags: regex, zimbra

I want to add a filter, based on regural expression, for body message for user on my Zimbra email server.

If the filter is triggered, email must be forward on specific address.

**For example:**

```
regex: /[0-9]/
User: test_user
Specific address: test_address@zimbra.com
```

Comment: this is great but what is the condition of your filtering trigger?

Comment: Condition? I'am want to create this filter. I want that if there are numbers in the body of the message sent to the address test_user@zimbra.com, there was a redirection of this letter to the address test_address@zimbra.com

Comment: https://www.zimbra.com/desktop7/help/en_US/filters/filtering_your_messages.htm

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions aren't supported, but you can use filespec-style wildcards like "?" for one character and "*" for zero or more characters.

[Check this zimbra community forums](https://forums.zimbra.org/viewtopic.php?t=10273)